# Calling njitted functions from an njitted main()

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, numba, function-call

On one hand I have a file `foo.py` that has a lot of `njit`-decorated functions such as `func1(args1)`, `func2(args2)`,...`funcN(argsN)`; on the other hand, I have a file `mainfoo.py` on which I will run the `njit`-decorated function `main()`.

`mainfoo.py` looks something like this

```
import foo
from numba import njit

@njit
def main():
   x1= foo.func1(args1)
   x2= foo.func2(args2)
   x3= foo.func3(args3)
   ...
   xN= foo.funcN(argsN)

   some_interactions_between_intermediate_arrays()
   boolean_indexing()
   more_fancy_indexing()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

As far as I know, python will throw an exception that states something along the lines of "Inside an njitted function `main()` you can't make a function call that calls other njitted functions defined outside the scope of the `main()`"

I am aware of one solution that is to manually redefine all the njitted functions inside `main()` (by redefine I mean copy and paste the functions from `foo.py` to the block inside `main()`), but that seems way too inefficient and unpythonic. Imagine what it is like to redefine 40 njitted functions, in possibly 40 njitted main functions, in 40 files on 40 occasions? This is why this "solution" seems like a really bad programming practice to me and I want to avoid it as much as I can.

I have only one question. How to overcome this pythonically?

Thank you in advance

---

EDIT: added some actions the `main()` will include

Comment: Why do you want do njit-decorate main()? If your functions are decorated in foo.py and you import foo, all the functions should be available in the scope of the script that holds the import. And jit-compiled upon call of course. I don't see where you have to *re-define* the functions.

Comment: @MrFuppes The reason I want njit-decorate `main()` is because after the calculations of `x1`, `x2`,.. there are quite a lot of interactions between them, such as boolean array conditioning, fancy indexing, more array vectorized operations. It is the aftermath/ handling of the intermediate results from the external `njitted` fucntions that needs to be njit-decorated as well.